# How to create new Async Task can keep CurrentUnitOfWork in aspboilerplate

Tags: c#, boilerplate

I Have API with unitofwork tag like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Book/ReadBookRequest")]
[UnitOfWork(scope: TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, isTransactional: true)]
```

Then I start new task inside api like this:

```
var taskBusiness = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    using (_abpSession.Use(tenantInfo.Id, _abpSession.UserId))
    {
         using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions { IsTransactional = false, Scope = System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required }))
        {
            CurrentUnitOfWork(1) //Current unit of work of uow
            await InsertDatabase();
            using (var uow2 = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new UnitOfWorkOptions { IsTransactional = false, Scope = System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required }))
            {
                //Save data to dabase
                CurrentUnitOfWork(2) //Current unit of work of uow2
                uow2.Complete()
            }
            CurrentUnitOfWork(1) //Now current unit of work of uow = null

        }

    }
});
```

Please help me know why my **CurrentUnitOfWork(1)** null after start new uow. And how to fix this in my situation.
My flow: 
Call api -> Response created and Task still running to save data to db
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is the underlying cause, but you shouldn't use `StartNew`. What happens if you remove the `StartNew` wrapper and just run the `async` code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace StartNew by Task.Run(()=> blockcode) it worked for me.Thank you Stephen Cleary.